# very small fonts and icons on 4k screens

Tags: eclipse, cfeclipse

I'm using CFeclipse on Windows 10 OS.

With the adaptation of new 4k resolution laptops. Eclipse displays small icons and fonts. Its also reported as a bug in https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=451693.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be a question. Or if it is, it's a support question for CFEclipse.

Answer (score 23):

The mentioned bug has been fixed, [**Eclipse automatically scales images on high-DPI monitors on Windows since Eclipse Neon (4.6)**](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/platform.php#swt-autoscale). So, make sure your [Eclipse IDE is up to date](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F).

If upgrading does not fix your issue, in `eclipse.ini` add the following line below the line `-vmargs` (see [Tweaking SWT's auto-scaling](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/platform.php#swt-autoscale-tweaks)):

```
-Dswt.autoScale=200
```

(In contrast to the compatibility mode of Windows, this is the way to get the **double-resolution icons**.)

Comment: I tried updating but my mylyn tasks are now showing errors. I tried reverting but it looks like the revert didn't work. Here is one of the error log. 
Error
Sun Jan 28 12:19:10 SGT 2018
Could not instantiate provider org.eclipse.egit.core.GitProvider for project X

Comment: I'm using Eclipse
Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627

Comment: The build ID contains the date: your IDE is almost four years old (20140224-0627 means 24 February 2014, 6:27 a. m.). You also have to update Mylyn. If upgrading does not work (because of third-party plug-ins), try to install Eclipse Oxygen.2 in a new folder.

Comment: I reverted back to my old copy of Eclipse. Build id: 20140224-0627 I can't use newer version of eclipse except for that build. I'm using cfeclipse and cfbuilder 3. Its working now and have to stick with the  Override High DPI scaling solution.

Comment: Same on linux, used `-Dswt.autoScale=100` because of system doubling size

Comment: Adding ```-Dswt.autoScale=200```to the ```eclipse.ini``` does work for 200% desktop scaling in Eclipse 2019-06 (4.12.0) but does not work with my preferred 175% scaling as there are no icons within the Eclipse toolbars shown anymore. 200% scaling does work but like a sharm as long as I used it as well on FullHD screens, with the drawback of having blurred fonts for all other apps.

Comment: `-Dswt.autoScale=quarter` works well for me. The only issue I have now is that I have some monitors with 100 scaling and some with 150 and eclipse uses the value from my main monitor and it looks too big when moved to a different display.

Comment: Works, but the icons are pretty blurry. I think Eclipse has some fine-tuning here, but this solution is good in the meantime.

Comment: Confirming -Dswt.autoScale=200 works with MCUXpresso, Eclipse based. File to edit for this IDE is mcuxpressoide.ini

Answer (score 19):

To solve the problem in Windows 10.

1. Right click Eclipse Icon
2. Select Properties
3. Compatibility Tab
4. Under Settings Section check 
   Override High DPI scaling behaviour. Scaling performed by.
   Select System.
5. Then Apply or Ok

I haven't encountered it yet in other application but this solution might also work for other apps that displays small icons and fonts.

This solution also works in Ultraedit,FastStone capture

The steps also helps for Coldfusion installer that appears too tiny to be readable or other Application installer in a 4k screen that shows everything too small.

Comment: Icon size increased but didn't get that sharp font resolution. How to fix it?

Comment: For sharp fonts use the other solution and add param -Dswt.autoScale=200 to eclipse.ini

Comment: Thanks @Vlad, this did the trick in both ways on my 4K laptop screen with Eclipse: either using 4K resolution scaled up 175% or attached to a screen/beamer with FullHD resolution. So an easy solution with one drawback: the fonts are blurred.

Answer (score 2):

I was having problems with a Windows 10 RDP connection using a Surface Pro machine.  A recent update made Eclipse virtually unusable.

This solution worked perfectly :

1. Right click Eclipse Desktop Icon
2. Select Properties
3. Compatibility Tab
4. Change high DPI settings
5. Override High DPI scaling behaviour. Scaling performed by. Select
   System.
6. Then Apply or OK

I then had to slightly adjust the font size within Eclipse itself.  I found I could use a slightly smaller font