# How to enlarge Eclipse toolbar?

Tags: eclipse, macos, ide, zooming, toolbar

I'm using Eclipse Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2) on macbook, connected to an external 27' monitor.

I know how to zoom in and out code written (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> / <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>),
but I cannot find anywhere, how to enlarge toolbar and package explorer.

[image: too small to read areas]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of zooming the base text font, you probably want to scale the whole UI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48474802/6505250

Comment: is it possible to do so in macOX?

Comment: Yes, in `eclipse.ini` just add the line `-Dswt.autoScale=200` below the line `-vmargs`.

Comment: i did this and restart Eclipse but nothing changed...

Comment: If scaling is already used, try `-Dswt.autoScale=400` and check the high DPI settings for the Eclipse application in macOS.