# How do i increase font size of project explorer pane in eclipse photon on mac

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-photon

[image]

How do I increase this size? Can anyone let me know
I am using a mac high sierra

Comment: Here, the font is used from the operating system. Eclipse provides only a possibility to scale everything (font, icons, etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/a/48474802/6505250

Comment: The line makes no difference on a mac

Comment: This should also work on macOS. Please show your `eclipse.ini`.

Comment: Its same as in link above, my line is below vm args

Comment: Maybe you're using an outdated version. This and more could be seen in `eclipse.ini`.