# How do I maximize all panels and text in my Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have Eclipse installed and the size of everything is very small. I couldn't find how to enlarge it on the Internet.
I'm not talking about increasing the font size. I'm talking about making Eclipse bigger. (I hope I was able to explain)
It looks like this:  [image]

Comment: Maybe there are some hints on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718093/eclipse-interface-icons-very-small-on-high-resolution-screen-in-windows-8-1

Comment: @csalmhof Outdated and with many answers that are not to be recommended.

Comment: In Windows, what is your text size (right-click on a free desktop area and choose _Display settings_)?

Comment: What do you mean by making Eclipse bigger? Do you want to increase the size of the complete window? Or do you want to increase single views? You can maximize them by the icons in the top right corner. You also can detach them by right click on the respective tab bar and choose "detach".

Comment: @howlger %100. but I can't set it to the default 125% because if I do, my java apps won't fit on the screen.

Comment: @Sascha I mean, as seen in the photo, the texts are very small and want to enlarge them. Windows 10's default eventual scale in Display Setting is 125%, eclipse looks normal at this setting. but I had to do it 100% because my java applications didn't fit on the screen. And it looks like in the photo.

Comment: So you want to increase the Eclipse font size, not the editor font size. That will probably be only manageable by increasing your Windows font size.

Comment: For [icon and fonts see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48474802/6505250), for [fonts only see here](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.17/platform.php#adjustable-view-fonts) (you might increase other fonts in the preferences as well).

Comment: @Sascha Since two releases all fonts can be changed, also the fonts used in trees and tables: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.17/platform.php#adjustable-view-fonts

Comment: @howlger Good to know it's adjustable in Eclipse now.

Comment: @howlger When I used `-Dswt.autoScale`, the icons looked too big, I took a measurement and realized that the eventual scale in Display Setting only affects text sizes.  So using [fonts only see here](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.17/platform.php#adjustable-view-fonts) worked. However, I think I tried all the fonts settings there(Colors and Fonts), but I could not change text of the buttons of file, edit, source, window.  Do you have an idea?

Comment: Since the menu are native Windows widgets (main menu and right-click menu, and also file chooser), you have to change this in Windows (the menu font and font size is the same as in other Windows applications, e.g. in the _File Explorer_ of Windows).